# App using Laravel 5.2. not working > 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

Tags: laravel-5, command-line-interface, guzzle6, guzzle

I have App running on Laravel 5.2.

It works fine until it tries to send emails through MailGun, and shows this error : [Web App Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6Bzw.png)

When I try to add Guzzle through SSH, I have this error below : 
[Guzzle CLI Install Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otXRz.jpg)

I'm lost, because I don't know much of Laravel, may anyone please help !

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Guzzle as required by Laravel documentation.

> The API based drivers such as Mailgun and Mandrill are often simpler and faster than SMTP servers. All of the API drivers require that the Guzzle HTTP library be installed for your application. You may install Guzzle to your project by adding the following line to your composer.json file: "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"

Then you have to run a

```
composer update
```

Or you can simply run in terminal

```
composer require "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"
```

Comment: My composer.json ,already had this instance .
Also, I can't simply do : 
––
composer update
––
it doesnt work, I have to write :

–– 
php composer.phar update
––

And doing so, it gives me same previous error shown in my CLI screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because Guzzle has not been installed in the first place because you are getting an error when trying to install it via composer.

> Could not scan for classes inside database which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

It seems that you are trying to load classes that are present in your composer.json file but not in your project directory.

Open your composer.json file, you should see something like this:

```
 "classmap": [
     "database",  /// <--- this line or similar 
],
```

You should first fix this error before running `composer install` again.

Comment: I didn't get you, is it good or bad to have this instance ? 
I do have it set as you said, in my composer.json

Comment: It is not a bad thing but the problem is that composer is unable to find its path. So you should fix the path in your composer.json and then run a composer install.

Comment: What should this path be, when my database folder is located in : 
public_html/local/

Comment: Place it in your root directory.

Comment: I did move the database folder from : public_html/local/  -> to -> public_html/  ..... 

I still have that error, shown in the CLI error screenshot I showed you before

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload`. If after this it still does not work, it is hard to find out what's wrong without having access to the project :)